# Pytest Exit Codes

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, exit-code

I've built my pytest class in the following manner:

```
class Test_Exit_Code(object):
    
  def setup_class(cls):
      If 2==2:
         # stop execution of the test class


  def test_a(self):
     assert True==True
```

As you can see inside the setup_class method i've inserted an IF , what i want to achieve in the if section is that if a certain condition appears to be true instead of the comment i want to return exit code 5 , i.e. no tests were collected .
so far i haven't found any way to do it.

Comment: I don't think you can do this: by the time `setup_class` is run, `pytest` has already completed the collection phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling `pytest.exit()`. Also it seems you are missing the `classmethod` decorator

```
class Test_Exit_Code:
  @classmethod
  def setup_class(cls):
      If 2==2:
         pytest.exit("test exit code setup failed", returncode=5)
```

- [pytest.exit](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=pytest%20exit#pytest.exit)
- [Setup / Teardown](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/xunit_setup.html#class-level-setup-teardown)

Comment: ye the decorator is missing , but not in the code